# API not able to receive POST Method from Airtable Script fetch-POST

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch-api, airtable

I am writing an Airtable script to post data from the record to my API however when I run the code in airtable and it hit my API it says the Method is OPTIONS and give **405 error**.

The API **works** as I try to post data **from postman**.

**The error in airtable says:**
"ypeError: Failed to fetch
at main on line 27
This error might be related to Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), a security mechanism that prevents websites from making malicious requests to other sites."

**Error in console is:**
"OPTIONS /api/webhook           405 Method Not Allowed "

**Below is my airtable script:**

```
let table = base.getTable('Onboarding');
let view = table.getView('Grid view');

let records = await view.selectRecordsAsync()
let record = records.records[0]

var data = {user: 
  {    
   "firstName": record.getCellValueAsString('firstName'),
   "LastName": record.getCellValueAsString('lastName'),
   "email": record.getCellValueAsString('email'),
   },
 }

console.log(JSON.stringify(data), "data")

let response = await fetch('https://1412-76-133-90-147.ngrok.io/api/webhook', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": 'application/json',
    "Accept": "application/json",
  }
})

let respJSON = await response.json()

console.log("Response", respJSON.text())

await table.updateRecordAsync(record.id, {
  response: respJSON,
});
```

**Backend- Node.js api/webhook.js**

```
    export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const { method } = req;
    console.log("Method:", method)
    switch (method) {
      case "POST":
        console.log("body", req.body)
        return getData(req, res);
      case "OPTIONS" : 
      res.setHeader("Allow", "POST");
        res.setHeader("Allow", ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"]);
        res.status(405).end(`Method ${method} Not Allowed`);
    }
  }

const getData = async (req, res) => {
    console.log("REQ*************************: ", req.body)
    res.status(200).json("Done")
}
```

Was added recently to check it it event hits the getData function.

> ```
>   case "OPTIONS" : 
>   res.setHeader("Allow", "POST");
> ```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Your backend should accept cors requests...can you share what are you using for your backend ?

Comment: Hi I added the backend code above

Comment: Well, your OPTIONS request is currently generating 405 because you explicitly have it emit that.

Comment: Thats is default. But when the Post request comes to the swuich it should direct to the getData() but its not reaching that point. Can you tell me what should I change in the code? Thanks

Comment: I resolved this issue. Thanks. I am unable to add an answer to this post to share how I resolved the issue of cors, as they have banned my account from doing this which is so shameful.